# Finding values in an unsorted list

Tags: python

so I have this assignment that is telling me to code a quiz about food. I pretty much ask some random questions about food and I have to display 2 of the top recommended foods from what they have answered. I made a list of 8 foods and a score for each one of the foods.

```
food=["pizza", "hotdogs", "chicken", "apples", "fish", "fries", "burgers", "donuts"]
score=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

print("Please answer each of the questions with yes or no.")
question=input("Do you eat meat?")
if question=="yes":
score[0]=score[0] + 1
score[1]=score[1] + 1
score[2]=score[2] + 1
score[4]=score[4] + 1
score[6]=score[6] + 1
question=input("Do you like fruits?")
if question=="yes":
score[3]=score[3] + 1
question=input("Do you like fried foods?")
if question=="yes":
score[2]=score[2] + 1
score[5]=score[5] + 1
score[4]=score[4] + 1
question=input("Do you like cheese?")
if question=="yes":
score[0]=score[0] + 1
score[1]=score[1] + 1
score[6]=score[6] + 1
question=input("Do you like food with holes in it?")
if question=="yes":
score[7]=score[7] + 1
question=input("Do you like to eat healthy?")
if question=="yes":
score[3]=score[3] + 1
question=input("Do you like bread?")
if question=="yes":
score[1]=score[1] + 1
score[6]=score[6] + 1
question=input("Do you like protein rich foods?")
if question=="yes":
score[2]=score[2] + 1
score[4]=score[4] + 1
question=input("Do you like dessert?")
if question=="yes":
score[3]=score[3] + 1
score[7]=score[7] + 1
question=input("Are you a vegan?")
if question=="yes":
score[3]=score[3] + 1
score[5]=score[5] + 1
score[7]=score[7] + 1
print(food)
print(score)

biggestsofar=0
for i in range(1, len(score)):
if (score[biggestsofar] < score[i]):
    biggestsofar = i
print("The biggest value is", biggestsofar)
print("Your recommended food is", food[biggestsofar])
```

This is what I have so far. The thing I am struggling with is displaying the 2 recommended foods. I found out how to display one of them (which is the code above^) but don't understand how to do the second. I have to somehow find the second biggest number in the list that gets created when they answer the questions. If someone can help me I would appreciate it.(And yes I had to use a loop to find the first one)

Comment: And no I am not just dumping my homework in here expecting someone to do it for me. I have been trying to do it for a while and cant seem to understand how to do it. I have also done most the work already and just need help with a small part of it.

Comment: looks like your code is not aligned properly. can you indent it properly please

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: The expected output is for it to say the 2 recommended foods. And to do that I need to find the 2 biggest numbers in the list called "score"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using Dictionary approach

While there are some interesting ways to solve this, i took both the food and questions, converted them into dictionary to help you get the answer.

Step 1: convert the food into a dictionary as keys, and value as scores.

Step 2: convert all the questions into a dictionary as keys and values as a list of items that needs to be scored. Use food list as the index to look up the key and increment. You can also use the value as list of food items.

Step 3: Iterate through the questions and ask the questions

Step 4: If answer is yes, use the food_score dictionary to increment the food by 1

Step 5: Sort the food_score dictionary in reverse order to get the top food items. The first 2 will be the top 2 food items.

```
food=["pizza", "hotdogs", "chicken", "apples", "fish", "fries", "burgers", "donuts"]
food_score = {f:0 for f in food}
questions = {'Do you eat meat ? ':[0,1,2,4,6],
             'Do you like fruits ? ':[3],
             'Do you like fried foods ? ':[2,4,5],
             'Do you like cheese ? ':[0,1,6],
             'Do you like food with holes in it ? ':[7],
             'Do you like to eat healthy ? ':[3],
             'Do you like bread ? ':[1,6],
             'Do you like protein rich foods ? ':[2,4],
             'Do you like dessert ? ':[3,7],
             'Are you a vegan ? ':[3,5,7]}
              
print("Please answer each of the questions with yes or no.")

#iterate through all the questions. k is question, 
#and v is the elements that needs incremented
for k,v in questions.items():
    q = input(k)
    if q.lower() == 'yes':
        #if answer is yes, then increment each food item by 1
        for i in v: food_score[food[i]] +=1

#sort the dictionary by value, in reversed order so first value is highest score
ranked_food = sorted(food_score, key=food_score.get, reverse=True)

print ('The biggest value is : ',food_score[ranked_food[0]])
print ('Your recommended food is : ', ranked_food[0])

print ('The second biggest value is : ', food_score[ranked_food[1]])
print ('Your second recommended food is : ', ranked_food[1])
```

The first two elements in `ranked_food` should give you the top 2 food per recommendation.

This solution is flexible and allows you to expand the list of food items and also to expand the question sets. The rest of the code can remain the same and will find the top two food recommendations.

## With your existing approach

If you are not allowed to use the new approach, you can do the following:

Assume you are allowed to use zip:

```
score_food = [(s,f) for s,f in zip(score,food)]
```

If zip is not allowed, then do this:

```
score_food = []
for i in range(len(food)):
    score_food.append((score[i],food[i]))
```

Now sort the list in descending order using this:

```
score_food.sort(reverse=True)
```

This will give you the scores in descending order. Since you stored them as a tuple, your score and food are paired together and you can identify each of them using the index.

`score_food[0]` will be the highest ranked. `score_food[0][0]` will be the score and `score_food[0][1]` will be the food.

Similarly, `score_food[1]` will be the second highest ranked. `score_food[1][0]` will be the score and `score_food[1][1]` will be the food.

If sort function is not allowed, use any sort logic (bubble sort is simplest to implement), and sort them in descending order. Remember `score_food[i][0]` will be the score where `i ranges from 0 thru 7` (since there are 8 food items).

Another option to implement this is:

```
score_index = []
for i, s in enumerate(score):
    score_index.append((s,i))
```

Now this is stored as a tuple with score and index pair. Again, this can be sorted and then referenced.

## code to sort in descending order

```
for i in range (len(score_food)-1):
    for j in range(i+1,len(score_food)):
        if score_food[i][0] < score_food[j][0]:
            score_food[i],score_food[j] = score_food[j],score_food[i]
```

Now you can reference `score_food[0]` It has highest_score and best_food.

`score_food[1]` will give you next highest_score and next best_food

Comment: This is very good, but the problem is I cannot use things that I have not learned yet. My teacher for some reason is strict with this so I would need to use what I used in the first part of my code to do the last part if that makes sense.

Comment: I appreciate the help but I cannot use zip and he also says to not sort the list. Here, let me send you the requirements for a better understanding.

Comment: Create a food quiz using lists and indexes.
List of 8 different foods.
Ask the user 10 vague questions to find out what their favorite food it out of the list.
Update the score.
Using a loop, find the "top 2 favourite foods" and print out the two recommended foods.
HINT #1 - use Google to help you find out how to implement, "finding the two biggest values in an unsorted list."
HINT #2 - DO NOT SORT THE SCORE LIST! This will mess things up for you as each score corresponds to a particular food.

Comment: I have given you almost everything. All you need to do is sort the score_food in descending order.

Comment: He is saying NOT to sort the score list. Which is true. It will mess up the index. However, he does not say you cannot SORT. If you can create a tuple of (score, food), then you can sort. The question does not prevent you from doing it. One way to sort a value while it is positional (like the score) is to combine it with the reference value (score, food). Then they are paired and can be sorted.

Comment: It works perfectly thanks. I have not really learned how "sort" works yet but I am assuming I will learn it soon.

Comment: I have added code to help you do the sort as well. There are many ways to sort. I just used a simple sort to give you highest score. You can use that as well

Answer (score 1):

I read your question wrong. Sorry :/
Ok, so you want the two largest values, right? My old code still works, but with some modifications. You need to find the index of that value.

```
lis = [0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1, 9]
sorted_lis = sorted(lis)
print(lis.index(sorted_lis[-1]), lis.index(sorted_lis[-2]))
```

Carrying over to your example:

```
score = [0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1, 9]
sorted_score = sorted(score)
print(food[score.index(sorted_score[-1])], food[score.index(sorted_score[-2])])
```

### Side note

I'm not sure if you know classes yet, but here's an alternate solution that is cleaner:

```
class Food(): # create a food class
    def __init__(self, type_):
        self.type = type_
        self.value = 0

    def increment(self):
        self.value += 1

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.value < other.value

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.value <= other.value

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.value > other.value

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self.value >= other.value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.type == other.type

foods = [Food("pizza"), Food("burger"), Food("hot dog")] # make some foods
food_STRING = []

for i in foods:
    food_STRING.append(i.type)

for i in range(10):
    food = input("Food:")
    foods[food_STRING.index(food)].increment()

sorted_food = sorted(foods)

print(sorted_food[-1].type, sorted_food[-2].type)
```

Comment: Alright, the answer should now be correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of the answer as having two buckets for which to you can assign a larger value that the current then check if one is larger than the other and swap them if so. I am assuming your assignment didn't allow for the `sort`/`sorted` functions:

```
largest, second_largest = (0, 0)
for item in range(len(score))):
    if score[item] > score[largest]:
        second_largest = largest
        largest = item
    elif score[largest] > score[item] > score[second_largest]:
        second_largest = item
print("The biggest value is", score[largest])
print("Your recommended food is", food[largest])
print("The second biggest value is", score[second_largest])
print("Your second recommended food is", food[second_largest])
```

Comment: Error in code above for instance `score = [100, 90, 80, 70, 90, 0, 50, 0]` gives the wrong answer.  Issue is you are comparing indexes (i.e. item) with scores.

Answer (score 0):

While other people have given good answers, I recommend you use a dictionary. A dictionary is when you correspond one value (usually a string) to another value (such as a boolean, number, or another string).

I think you should implement this in your code:

```
# Creating a dictionary (food: score)
my_dictionary = {
    'pizza': 0,
    'hotdogs': 0,
    'chicken': 0,
    'apples': 0,
    'fish': 0,
    'fries': 0,
    'burgers': 0,
    'donuts': 0,
}

# Creating a function to change the food and score. 
# Execute this function to change your score
def change_score(food, score):
    global my_dictionary
    my_dictionary[food] = score
```

I'll let you use this to try and finish your program yourself, but this should hopefully be helpful.
This site should help you understand dictionaries:

Comment: I would like to use dictionaries but the problem is I cannot use things that my teacher has not taught me yet, meaning I can only use from what I used above to do the last part of my code.